# Implicit Style for application

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Implicit Style not working in App.xaml, but is working with local page resources. How do I make a global style for a control?

```
<navigation:Page.Resources>
 <Style TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Navy" />
 </Style>
</navigation:Page.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="StilDict.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
 </ResourceDictionary>
```

In StilDict.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
  ,,,, and what you use else>
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyleNavyOnRed" TargetType="Button">
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Navy" />
</Style>
```

using style anywhere on your project

```
 <UserControl>
    <Button Style={StaticResource ButtonStyleNavyOnRed} Content="Yahoo! :)"/>
 </UserControl>
```

Important Note if you delete x:Key="ButtonStyleNavyOnRed" part all of your Target types  get this style, but not Button derived objects. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style(v=vs.95).aspx

Hope Helps!

Comment: Ohh you are right .just need to delete x:Key="ButtonStyleNavyOnRed" part. Then it works I tested. Thanks for warning.

Comment: Yes, I am using the Merge dictionary in the app.xaml. From what I read when you do not specify a key on a style it will implicitly set the style to all controls of the TargetType in the declaration. I am trying to get this to work globally not just from within the page resources as I have shown above. I am not sure what to change to fix this. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: I think you didnt see my note and link,you are right remove key attrb, it works,no needs to set a style

Comment: No, I did, for whatever reason my designer was unstable - all my styles where showing as not found -> rebuilt and reopened and things are ok now. Like it might was some how missing the Merge for the dictionaries at that time - though it was there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works for buttons!

```
<Style TargetType="ButtonBase">
 <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
 <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Navy" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Does it works for just buttonbase objects,or alo for buttons?

Comment: It should be all objects that are derived from ButtonBase. It is weird that TargetType=ButtonBase worked initially and then it just quit working and I switched to TargetType=Button and it works again???

Comment: Follow the link end of my post MS says "If you set the style implicitly, the style is applied only to the types that match the TargetType exactly and not to elements derived from the TargetType value"